# Extract fields from matrix using awk

Tags: sed, awk

I'm trying to extract fields from a rectangular matrix in a file "input.dat" using awk which is as follows

```
Name value1 value2 value3
A 0 100 200
B 100 0 200
C 0 0 0
D 50 50 50
E 0 90 90
```

to get the output

```
A.value1=0
A.value2=100
A.value3=200
B.value1=100
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1 { split( $0, a); next } 
    { for( i=2; i <= NF; i++ )
        print $1 "." a[i] "=" $i
    }' input.dat
```

Or:

```
awk 'NR==1 { split( $0, a); next }
    { for( i=2; i <= NF; i++ ) 
        printf "%s.%s=%s\n", $1, a[i], $i
    }' input.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my little dirty awk :

```
awk '{ 
    print $1 ".value1=" $2; 
    print $1 ".value2=" $3; 
    print $1 ".value3=" $4;  
    }' data
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '1{s/\S*\s*//;h;d};G;s/^/\n/;:a;s/\n\(\S*\) \(\S\+\)\([^\n]*\)\n\(\S*\) */\1.\4=\2\n\n\1\3\n/;ta;s/\n\n\S* *\n$//' file
```